# Convert epoch time to human readable time in google analytics

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-analytics

I am running the below query in google analytics to convert a epoch timestamp to human readable form

```
select DATEADD(s, doj, '19700101')
from employee
where emp_id is not null
```

Where `doj` is the column name with epoch value

But the query is failing with:

> function not found: DATEADD

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Are you sure it has the DATEADD function?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Are you sure about your environment? [DATE_ADD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) in BigQuery has a very different function signature.

Answer (score 0):

The way I prefer:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(1615878186)               # 2021-03-16 07:03:04 UTC    
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1615878186000)     # 2021-03-16 07:03:04 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1615878186000000)  # 2021-03-16 07:03:04 UTC
```

Comment: I ran the query "select timetsamp(doj)
from employee
where emp_id is not null  "   got error :- No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP(STRING, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATE, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATETIME, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thats because you are using MySQL whereas OP is using SQL Server.